# error[E0614]: type `<T as pallet_nfts::Config>::CollectionId` cannot be dereferenced

Tags: xcm, nft

I want to pass the collection id in the from of MultiAssets to transfer it to the another chain. But i'm facing this issue

```
error[E0614]: type `<T as pallet_nfts::Config>::CollectionId` cannot be dereferenced
   --> xnft/src/lib.rs:201:30
    |
201 |             let assets: MultiAssets = (*collection_id).try_into().map_err(|()| Error::<T>::BadVersion)?;
    |                     

              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message  indicates that you're trying to dereference a type `<T as pallet_nfts::Config>::CollectionId`, but it is not a type that can be dereferenced.

To resolve this issue, you should avoid dereferencing the `collection_id` directly. Instead, you can use the `Into` trait to convert it into the desired type. Here's an example of how you can modify your code to fix the issue:

```rust
let assets: MultiAssets = collection_id.into();
```

By using the `Into` trait, the `collection_id` will be automatically converted into the appropriate type, as long as there is an implementation of `Into<MultiAssets>` for `CollectionId`.